# Can you add parameters to Actions?

Tags: scala, playframework

Say I have a Action and I want it to optionally force https.

How can I add a parameter to a custom action?

```
import play.api.mvc._

def onlyHttps[A](action: Action[A]) = Action.async(action.parser) { request =>
  request.headers.get("X-Forwarded-Proto").collect {
    case "https" => action(request)
  } getOrElse {
    Future.successful(Forbidden("Only HTTPS requests allowed"))
  }
}
```

So in my controller:

```
def index = onlyHttps(false) {
  // ..
}
```

Another area is I want to check if the currently logged in user has a certain level of permission, so I want to pass the permission type(s) as a parameter to my custom actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add [another parameter list](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/135):

```
def onlyHttps[A](limitToHttps: Boolean)(action: Action[A]) = /* 
    Your implementation here.  You can access `limitToHttps` here. */
```